# По нажатию на кнопку записать квадрат введенного числа

Tags: javascript, html

Даны два инпута и кнопка. В первый пользователь вводит число. По нажатию на кнопку запишите во второй инпут квадрат введенного числа.

```js
let elem41 = document.querySelector('#elem-4-1');
let elem42 = document.querySelector('#elem-4-2');
let btn4 = document.querySelector('#btn-4');

btn4.addEventListener('click', function () {
    elem42.innerHTML += Math.pow(elem41, 2);
})
```

```html
<input type="number" id="elem-4-1" value="">
    <input type="number" id="elem-4-2" value="">
    <input type="submit" id="btn-4">
```

Comment: Как ты думаешь, у инпута есть свойство innerHTML?  и как думаешь, что именно находится в elem41 по-твоему?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Расшифрую комментарий, почему код не работает:

1. У поля ввода (инпутов) нет свойства `innerHTML`. Оно есть у обычных элементов, типа `div`, `p`, `h1`. Для инпутов используют свойство `value`. То есть, чтобы получить введенное содержимое поля надо писать `elem42.value = ...`. Такие вещи можно загуглить, например "javascript как получить содержимое input".
2. Точно так же в математической функции возведения в степень `Math.pow()` нужно указывать не сам элемент, а значение элемента.

```js
let elem41 = document.querySelector('#elem-4-1');
let elem42 = document.querySelector('#elem-4-2');
let btn4 = document.querySelector('#btn-4');

btn4.addEventListener('click', function () {
  elem42.value = Math.pow(elem41.value, 2);
})
```

```html
<input type="number" id="elem-4-1" value="">
<input type="number" id="elem-4-2" value="">
<input type="submit" id="btn-4">
```